# With Bazel, how can you retrieve stamped information from a binary?

Tags: bazel, stamp

The manual goes into the details of how you can stamp binaries (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html) with build information.

My question is "how can you read that information from a binary?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of binary you're talking about. Most of them are very poorly documented. I've worked out how to do it for some languages, mainly by reading the Bazel source code.

For C++, you set the (undocumented) `linkstamp` attribute of a `cc_library` to a `.cc` file which will have `BUILD_SCM_REVISION`, `BUILD_TIMESTAMP`, and the rest defined to the appropriate values when it's compiled. [bazelbuild/bazel#2893](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2893) is an open bug to document this better.

For a `genrule`, you set the `stamp` attribute to `1`, and then it can access `bazel-out/volatile-status.txt`/`bazel-out/stable-status.txt` with the information. [bazelbuild/bazel#944](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/944) talks about this a bit.

I've seen Bazel code for doing something with a `.properties` file for Java, but I've never actually figured out how to use it.